# ExcelConnection manager dynamic file path in SSIS

Tags: ssis

When i tried to give connection string in the form of a variable to "Excel Connection Manager", it gives me the below error.

the connection string format is not valid. it must consist of one or more components of the form x=y seperated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Answer (score 4):

Since you want a dynamic file path, when you are setting up the Expression for the Excel Connection Manager, you are probably selecting **ConnectionString** as a property in the **Property Expressions Editor**. This results in the error you specified in your question.

What you actually need to select is the **ExcelFilePath** property. Add your variable in the Expression field afterwards as you would normally do.

Answer (score 1):

You should give us more information. What's the value of you variable when the error pops up? To exactly what property have you assigned this variable?
Anyway, I suspect that you didn't set [Delay validation] property of your connection manager to True - without it ssis check if you connection manager is ok, before you even assign value to the variable (which is dynamic and happens during execution in some loop, I suppose).